# Install4j : How to execute command line java -jar filename.jar at the end of installation

Tags: java, jar, install4j

In Intall4j, at the end of installation I just want to initialize something by executing a command line like:

`java -jar filename.jar`

How can I archive this task with `install4j`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add a "Run executable or batch file" action to the "Installation screen" and set the following properties:

"Executable" property: ${installer:sys.javaHome}/bin/java

"Arguments" property:  -jar; filename.jar (in the editor one argument per line)

Comment: Note that, at least in version 6.x of Install4J, when I had a space after the argument it failed with a Java error when attempting to run the command.