# How do I configure install4j to run a java executable jar file which contains other jar files?

Tags: java, install4j, onejar

I have java an executable jar file that has many other jar files embedded in it. It uses [simon tuffs onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/version-0.95/) to accomplish this. The jar runs correctly when I double-click it, or issue 'java -jar myApp.jar' from the command prompt. The jar file has a manifest.mf containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
One-Jar-Expand: expand,doc
```

Install4j correctly copies this jar file to my bin folder, but the 'myApp.exe' that it creates fails to launch. I get:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ndi.foreCee.programs.MyApp

or:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot

depending on what I plug into install4j's Configure Java invocation page 'Main class'. I've set 'Class path:' to 'Archive bin\myApp.jar'.

Can anyone tell how to configure install4j to build an exe that just issues 'java -jar myApp.jar', using the embedded jre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating my ant build and removing simon tuffs one-jar and replacing it with:
 
as described in [Including external jar-files in a new jar-file build with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770071/including-external-jar-files-in-a-new-jar-file-build-with-ant)
. After that, the Install4J launcher worked as advertised (and as M2E67 described).

Answer (score 4):

Add a "Run executable or batch file" action to the "Installation screen" and set the following properties:

"Executable" property: ${installer:sys.javaHome}/bin/java

"Arguments" property: -jar; filename.jar (in the editor one argument per line)

[Install4j : How to execute command line java -jar filename.jar at the end of installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634695/install4j-how-to-execute-command-line-java-jar-filename-jar-at-the-end-of-ins)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell how to configure install4j to build an exe that just >issues 'java -jar myApp.jar', using the embedded jre?

The launcher generated by install4j does not execute `java`at all, it uses JNI to create the JVM.

You can start the executable from the command line with the parameter `/create-i4j-log` to get a log file that shows the parameters that are passed to the JVM.